# Using ~/.dircolors in fish shell

Tags: bash, shell, fish, rc

I just recently switched to the fish shell from bash and I am having trouble sourcing my dircolors template file to get custom colors to appear for certain file extensions.

In bash, I was sourcing a template from `~/.dircolors/dircolors.256dark`. The **dircolors.256dark** template has different file types mapped to different colors. For example, when I use `ls`, all `.wav` files will appear in orange. This was being sourced in my `~/.bash_profile` like so:

```
# uses dircolors template
eval $(gdircolors ~/.dircolors/dircolors.256dark)

# Aliases
alias ls='gls --color=auto'
```

However, fish doesn't really use an rc file but instead sources from a `config.fish`, file but the syntax for certain operations is different in fish.

I'm trying to figure out how I would be able to accomplish this in fish. I like being able to visually distinguish different file types by color so this could potentially be a deal breaker for me if there is no way of doing this in fish.

P.S.

For clarity, I am not trying to simply change the colors of directories or executable files, but files with different file extensions. For example if I did `ls` in a directory, I would get the following:

```
my_file.py  # this file would be green for example
my_file.js  # this file would be yellow
my_file.wav # this file would be orange
```

EDIT: I used homebrew on macOS for dircolors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was actually pretty simple. Within my `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file, I just needed to drop the "$" from the `eval` statement. So it would look like this:

```
# uses dircolors template
eval (gdircolors ~/.dircolors/dircolors.256dark)

# Aliases
alias ls='gls --color=auto'
```